# What's the solution for $\max_{x\in(0,1]}: \{-1-x\}$

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

What's the solution for the following optimization problem? Is the constraint set convex?

> $$\max_{x\in(0,1]}:\{-1-x\}$$

Comment: It doesn't exist.  Perhaps you mean $\sup$ instead of $\max$?

Answer (score 1):

It has already be mentioned in the comments above that the maximum doesn't exist. Note that 
$$
\{-1-x : x\in (0, 1]\} = [-2, -1)
$$
and this set does not have a maximum. Remember that the maximum is an upper bound that is itself a member of the set.

As also mentioned in the comment above, this set does have a supremum which is the least upper bound. You see that $-1$ is this least upper bound.